# Error encountered when running localstack

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to run [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) for the first time. I am using link mint 17. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Starting local dev environment. CTRL-C to quit.
Starting mock ES service (http port 4578)...
Starting local Elasticsearch (http port 4571)...
Starting mock S3 (http port 4572)...
Starting mock SNS (http port 4575)...
Starting mock SQS (http port 4576)...
Starting mock SES (http port 4579)...
Starting mock SSM (http port 4583)...
Starting mock API Gateway (http port 4567)...
Starting mock DynamoDB (http port 4569)...
Starting mock DynamoDB Streams service (http port 4570)...
Starting mock Firehose service (http port 4573)...
Starting mock Lambda service (http port 4574)...
Starting mock Kinesis (http port 4568)...
Starting mock Redshift (http port 4577)...
Starting mock Route53 (http port 4580)...
Starting mock CloudFormation (http port 4581)...
Starting mock CloudWatch (http port 4582)...
2018-10-29T22:06:03:WARNING:infra.py: Service "elasticsearch" not yet available, retrying...
2018-10-29T22:06:11:ERROR:localstack.services.generic_proxy: Error forwarding request: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=4564): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f050959e5c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 83, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/user/venv35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f050959e5c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

What should i do to fix this? I already installed the dependencies, like java, maven, npm, pip, and python

Comment: What is supposed to run on port 4564 (the port that it is failing to connect to in you log)? Googling their github https://github.com/localstack/localstack/search?q=4564&unscoped_q=4564 it seems to be DynamoDB? In your log above DynamoDB is starting on a different port though...

Comment: This feels better suited for research on https://superuser.com/